# Is there a way to Parse String to DateTime, when the string comes with different formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am working on building a console application which read a .csv file and add the values to the database. now i have some CSV columns which store date time values.
But those column sometimes contain the datatime with seconds while sometimes it does not. here is a sample of some data for the date field:-

```
03/30/2016 10:55:49
04/01/2016 11:02
```

now when i try to parse the above string into a date-time as follow:-

```
formattedDateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[DateCreatedIndex], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

i will get the following exception when i try to parse the second date :-

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

so can anyone advice on this please? how i can make my Parse more dynamic to work on date formats with seconds or without seconds??
Thanks

Comment: The second parameter of ParseExact (the format) could be also an array of formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overload that supports multiple formats:

```
string[] formats = {"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" };
DateTime formattedDateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[DateCreatedIndex], formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: and will it apply them in order, or it will chose the best match ?

Comment: @johnG: first match wins, so i would use default format first and better avoid formats like `MM/dd` + `dd/MM`, otherwise you might get no exception but an incorrect `DateTime`. If you want to see the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,4279d8830fc9e88f,references)

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) can also takes multiple formats:

```
var formats = new []
{
    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
};
var dates = "03/30/2016 10:55:49;04/01/2016 11:02".Split(';')
    .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
```